# What Wordpress Hook Is Used Before Signup Data is Saved?

Tags: wordpress

I need hook which is working before signup data save on new user and blog registration on BP or WP 3.0.3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Administrative_Filters

**create_user_query**

applied to the query used to save a new user's information to the database, just prior to running the query.